# Why doesn't my .OBJ file appear in viewport and in the outliner after importing?

Tags: 3d-view, import, outliner

I'm very new to blender, so I apologize for wasting your time if this has a simple solution. I downloaded some files off of gumroad, extracted them, and have them ready to go to import, but whenever I do click the blue button that says "import," the model doesn't appear in viewport and in Outliner. The .OBJ format is the only one that doesn't give an error message. I would really appreciate it if someone could assist me since I've been researching for a solution for days.

Edit: I realized I can open the model from the file, which will open blender, but I want to know the answer still just in case I want to add the model to my project.

Comment: Hello could you please share one of these objects?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AjAp7N_p0jIchV4PP-spA83UvCWk?e=ICVt7z

Comment: I can't see any .obj, only .fbx and they seem to work fine